# Android: Showing cards like layout as in Google Keep

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I was wondering how to show the snapshot of my notes, checklists, images in the grid view. I have no trouble creating the grid view but creating a preview of it is the challenge I'm facing right now as I need to add different type of views(text, checklist, imageview) to the grid according to their time of creation. Works fine for a single type of view like image or text only.

Or in other words. How do I add the different views dynamically to the GridView Adapter?

All or any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Download this git https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/androiddev/tree/master/GuiExample
Use StaggeredGridView, follow this link http://gmariotti.blogspot.in/2013/03/gui-like-google-keep.html?view=sidebar

Comment: I'm not talking about the GUI. I want to know how to show a preview of my items in the GridView. I'm aware of GMariotti's blog. Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking forward to get the answer too!

Answer (score 3):

They surely do not use a GridView for google Keep - but probably an [Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) nonetheless.

To use different Views with your Adapter you can use different View types:

1. Override [`getViewTypeCount()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) to return the number of View types you support.
2. Return the appropriate type in [`getItemViewType(int position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) for this specific item.
3. Create the correct View in [`getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29).

Keep in mind that the rules for recycling, ViewHolder and so on still apply. For multiple types recycling only happens for the correct type.

[Marcus Körner](https://plus.google.com/115465922685935745669/posts/RUTycHWdppG) [shared a gist by Jake Wharton on G+ recently](https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/5423616) that might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely Google is using something similar to [GridLayout](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html), if not actually using a GridLayout.

Chances are the layout is also created programmatically to allow for the widgets to be different sizes based on the content that they each display.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [recycle view with stagged](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView)

This manage make all what you need StaggeredGridLayoutManager
or look at this sorce [Heterogenous Layouts inside RecyclerView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView)

Answer (score 1):

```
recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new                  
StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

        initData();
        MasonryAdapter adapter=new MasonryAdapter(productList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        SpacesItemDecoration decoration=new SpacesItemDecoration(16);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);
```

Comment: what is SpacesItemDecoration?